# Send custom user fields to twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I'm writing my first Drupal 8 theme.

Now for a block I need all some custom fields of the user. So that I can use it in my theme.

I create a theme file with collectionmanager_preprocess_html method.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
 *
 * Adds body classes if certain regions have content.
 */
function collectionmanager_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
// Load the current user.
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

// get field data from that user
$firstname = $user->field_first_name->value;
$lastname = $user->field_last_name->value;

$variables['custom_firstname'] = $user->field_first_name->value;
$variables['custom_lastname'] = $user->field_last_name->value;
}
```

If I'm correct I can access the variables in twig with {{custom_firstname}}. But it show always a null value. Can someone help me with this? I can't find my issue on this. The variable $firstname and $lastname contains the correct values.

Comment: What is the template name?

Comment: I need to use the variable in page.html.twig file.

Comment: if u need this variable in page.html.twig you should use preprocess_page instead of preprocess_html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

collectionmanager_preprocess_**html**() prepares variables for **html**.html.twig template. For **page**.html.twig the of the function name should be collectionmanager_preprocess**_page**(). The same pattern should be used for other theme hooks (view, block, field etc).

Comment: When I debug my source after changing the method name it gives me a ResourceNotFoundException.

Comment: That seems irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: I forgot to clear the cache after change the method name. Tnx